# Which server will be best for website Xampp or Windows Server 2008

Tags: server, xampp

I'm using Xampp server (Apache server ) for my website however it has some connectivity issues with the internet and I can't access it online. So I was advised that I must use Windows server 2008. Let me know if this is a good idea or not. The Xampp has issue with port forward through Dynamic IP. Let me know the best option that I have.

Comment: If  xampp is okay for website then please let me know how can I open a stealth port. My ports are stealth but not closed.

Answer (score 0):

To connect your Apache webserver to the internet you don't need to do any local port-forwarding, you should try port-forwarding with your router. If you're runing linux, you should type `ifconfig` and look for your default gateway, that's the ip your router is using.

Some ISP's force you to use their own website to port-forward though. Standard, apache always runs on port 80, which you should allow in your firewall using the TCP protocol.

Perhaps you could explain your situation more, Windows Server won't make the hosting easier though. You will most likely encounter the same problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my problem. I've tried those auto port forward softwares but the issue is my Router (Huwaei E8732 ) is not listed in those softwares or any other internet website. Thanks for advising to stick with apache. I will keep that in mind.